# Nuances in Second Borel-Cantelli Lemma for Pairwise Independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm trying to understand the proof of Second Borel-Cantelli Lemma for Pairwise Independence. I'm using the one stated [here](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~bin06/Stochastic-Analysis/ma414soln5.pdf), in Q2. I think, that I've got the main idea:

1. Assume, that $S_n$ is a number of "successfull" events $A_i$ from $i=1..n$;
2. Using pairwise independence show, that $var(S_n) \le \mathbb{E}(S_n)$;
3. Using Chebycheff’s Inequality show, that $\mathbb{P}(S < \infty) \xrightarrow {n \rightarrow \infty} 0$ and, consequently, $\mathbb{P}(S < \infty) = 0$;
4. Finally, as $S$ is the number of successes as the $n$ goes to infinity, $\mathbb{P}(A_n) = 0$, q.e.d.

What I don't quite understand in the [proof](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~bin06/Stochastic-Analysis/ma414soln5.pdf) is this:

1. Why the product of expectations when $i \neq j$ is zero?
2. How the fact, that $I(A_i)$ is distributed by Bernoulli is used? Obviously, it should help to mpve from $\sum [\mathbb{E}(I(A_i) - \mathbb{E}(A_i))^2]$ to $\sum \mathbb{P}(A_i)$, but I cannot see, how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For $i\neq j$,
   $$
   \mathbb{E}[(I(A_i)-\mathbb{E}[I(A_i)])(I(A_j)-\mathbb{E}[I(A_j)])]=
   \mathbb{E}[I(A_i)-\mathbb{E}[I(A_i)]]\cdot \mathbb{E}[I(A_j)-\mathbb{E}[I(A_j)]]
   $$
   by pairwise independence; but
   $$
   \mathbb{E}[I(A_j)-\mathbb{E}[I(A_j)]]
   = \mathbb{E}[I(A_j)]-\mathbb{E}[I(A_j)] = 0
   $$
   by linearity.
2. For a r.v. $X$ distributed as Bernoulli($p$), $\mathrm{Var} X = p(1-p) \leq p = \mathbb{E}[X]$.

Comment: about the second part: I get this formula, but don't understand, how we got from the expectation squared on the left (when $i = j$) to just $\mathbb{P}(A_i)$

Comment: That's not the expectation squared, that the expectation *of the square*. It's the variance. @OlgaZhukova